# Text vocabulary coverage using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a trained `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer` object on some corpus. When vectorizing a new document, the vector contains only the tokens that appear in the vectorizer's vocabulary.
I'd like to add another feature to the vector which is the vocabulary coverage, or in other words, the percentage of tokens that are in the vocabulary.

Here's my code:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    "good morning sunshine",
    "hello world",
    "hello sunshine",
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

def get_vocab_coverage(vectorizer, sent):

    preprocessor = vectorizer.build_preprocessor()
    tokenizer = vectorizer.build_tokenizer()

    processed = preprocessor(sent)
    tokenized_license = tokenizer(processed)
    count = sum(w in vectorizer.vocabulary_ for w in tokenized_license)
    
    return count / len(tokenized_license)

get_vocab_coverage(vectorizer, "hello world") # => 1.0
get_vocab_coverage(vectorizer, "hello to you") # => 0.333
```

The problem with this code is that it's not very pythonic, it uses an internal sklearn's variable and is not very scalable. Any idea how I can improve it? or is there an existing method that does the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` method of `CountVectorizer` may be useful:

```py
def get_vocab_coverage(vectorizer, sent: str):

  preprocessor = vectorizer.build_preprocessor()
  tokenizer = vectorizer.build_tokenizer()

  processed = preprocessor(sent)
  tokenized_license = tokenizer(processed)

  if len(tokenized_license):
    return vectorizer.transform([sent]).sum() / len(tokenized_license)

  return 0
```

Note wrapping sample string to list before passing to `transform` (because it expects batch of documents, not one string), and also handling `len == 0` case (no need to catch error dividing by zero). Few things to point out:

- method `transform` returns sparse vector, so `sum` works fast
- `CountVectorizer` make no advantage of passing documents by batches to `transform`, [inside](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1207) there is ordinary for-cycle, so function `get_vocab_coverage` written for processing one example is enough
- `transform` expects raw documents, so function tokenize one example twice (explicitly while creating `tokenized_license` and implicitly inside `transform`), and it seems there is no simple way to avoid it (only return to previous version); if that's critical consider rewriting [`_count_vocab`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1192) method with `preprocessed_documents` argument instead of `raw_documents`

Comment: This is great! also since `transform` expects a batch it should be more efficient. Thanks!